# glDrawElements display issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, fbx

I want to draw object (cube) with texture in openGL ES 2, but got strange (as for me) result.

Obj that i want to draw - extracted from FBX file and has data like (also i can extract Normals but i don't use them so just skip):

```
----Indices----24
0
1
2
3
4
7
6
5
0
4
5
1
1
5
6
2
2
6
7
3
4
0
3
7

----Coordinates(Vertises)----72
1 1 -1 
1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 
-1 1 -1 
1 0.999999 1 
-1 1 1 
-1 -1 1 
0.999999 -1 1 
1 1 -1 
1 0.999999 1 
0.999999 -1 1 
1 -1 -1 
1 -1 -1 
0.999999 -1 1 
-1 -1 1 
-1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 1 
-1 1 1 
-1 1 -1 
1 0.999999 1 
1 1 -1 
-1 1 -1 
-1 1 1 

----Texture UV----48
0.499999 9.7692e-05
0.499999 0.333364
0.250049 0.333364
0.250049 9.78112e-05
0.250049 0.666633
0.499999 0.666633
0.499999 0.9999
0.250049 0.9999
0.74995 0.333366
0.74995 0.666633
0.5 0.666633
0.5 0.333367
0.499998 0.333366
0.499998 0.666632
0.250048 0.666633
0.250048 0.333366
0.25005 0.333367
0.25005 0.666633
0.000100091 0.666633
0.000100024 0.333367
0.749953 0.666639
0.749953 0.333373
0.999903 0.333373
0.999903 0.666639
```

So i bund buffers :

```
- (void)bindBuffer
{
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertextArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertextArray);
    //vertises
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * _drawModel.numberOfVertices, _drawModel.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, NULL);
    //textures
    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * _drawModel.numberOfTextCoords, _drawModel.texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributes[ATTRIBUTES_TEXTURE_COORDINATE]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attributes[ATTRIBUTES_TEXTURE_COORDINATE], 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, NULL);
    //indises
    glGenBuffers(1, &_indisesBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indisesBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * _drawModel.numberOfIndises, _drawModel.indises, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}
```

and draw them

```
- (void)draw
{
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(_programm);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertextArray);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _mvpMatrix.m);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture.name);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _drawModel.numberOfIndises, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

As result i got next:

if i use `GL_LINES` mode (just for reference):

[image]

and if i use `GL_TRIANGLES`:

[image]

Texture (for reference)

[image]

So looks like `gl machine` do not draw some additional triangles, but i stack why it's happens and how to fix it... 
Any suggestions?

---- UPDATE-----

The problem was in incorrect Indices index and missing part of them, after correction i got (thanks to @**codetiger**)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 24 vertices but the indices are referring only the first 7 vertices. Which means, the indices are wrong.

Try feeding the indices in order

```
 0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3,   //front
 4,  5,  6,  4,  6,  7,   //right
 8,  9,  10, 8,  10, 11,  //back
 12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,  //left
 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,  //upper
 20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23
```

Comment: i also try to perform test with indices as u suggest (from 1 to 23) - result it's a little bit more better but not as expected..., i guess that i should have 8 indices indexes (because cube has 8 verises), so this should be combination for triangles in range from 0 to 8, am i right?

Comment: @gbk I've corrected the order of vertices, this should work for you.

Comment: thanks, u are right, i think that indicess is for triangles, not for vertises - my fall, many thanks for u advice, pleasee see update